# Should I care about IE Quirks mode?

Tags: html, css

I have just tested my website in IE quirk mode and it look awful.

Should I care about the IE quirk mode? And if yes is there a tool that could help my write CSS for the Quirks mode.

Update my doctype:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="da">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should I care about the IE quirk mode?

Only insofar as you should use a Doctype that triggers Standards mode so you don't have a deal with Quirks mode.

Comment: I have posted my doctype can you tell my if it triggers quirks mode?

Comment: @Railsbeginner: It shouldn't but it still might if your html violates the strict doctype.

Comment: According to Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), your doctype will put IE 6 into quirks mode and IE 7 into "Almost Standard" mode.

Comment: XHTML comes with [a lot of hoops to jump through](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#compatGuidelines) and is very rarely worth the pain. I'd suggest [HTML 4.01 Strict](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.1) or the [HTML 5 Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/author/syntax.html#the-doctype). I'd also recommend UTF-8. There is very little reason to use ISO-8859-1 in the 21st century (i.e. you probably should have stopped using it a decade ago).

Comment: @Chris Shaffer: It's not the doctype declaration that puts IE in quirks mode, but the XML declaration above it.

Comment: Or more precisely, the fact that there is stuff before the Doctype.

Answer (score 2):

Depends.

If you do not need to support older versions of IE, specifically 6 and maybe 7, I would ignore it.

The only reasons to support those browsers are

1. because the boss/client says so.
2. you have a large user base utilizing said browser.

**EDIT**

From the comment on @Quentin's answer...  you can check how your browser is displaying by copying this into your address bar

```
javascript:m=(document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat')?'Standards':'Quirks';window.alert('You are in ' + m + ' mode.');
```

script from http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/quirksmode.html